# Use Ionic 5 date picker in Ionic 6

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5, ionic6

Hi i am using ionic 5 for my project and recently migrated to ionic 6 everything looks great but one thing concerns me is the datetime picker i want that in old style this way please help!

[image]

Comment: Plz share some code...

Comment: plz check my code in my git https://github.com/sai7135/ionic6.git fork it make changes and re comment your git if possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using some hacking. The `ion-datetime` accepts a property named `yearValues` where you can create 'custom' year values.

`html`:

```
  <div class="hacking-datetime">
    <ion-datetime presentation="year" [yearValues]="yearValues"></ion-datetime>
    <ion-datetime presentation="month-year"></ion-datetime>
  </div>
```

`ts`:

```
yearValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30];
```

`css`:

```
.hacking-datetime {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[Demo Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5iHP.png)

Although it will be visually the same as before(after some css of course) programatically you'll have to do a lot of work. And, as I said before it's a hack, so I really do not reccomend you using it :-)

Comment: thanks that exactly what i want....

Comment: How to get the selected date @Josemar

Comment: You get the values of both ion-datetime and use the Date class or date-fns to combine them into one date

Comment: @JosemarSilva 
- what about February, or based on month it can be 30, or 31 .

Comment: @Mustak_Talukder ion-datetime has an ionChange event which you can use on the second datetime to check the selected month and update the yearValues array accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
From my understanding there is no way to use the old style UI. See more here: [Use ion-datetime v4 instead of v6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70378325/15947768)

I think your best bet is to use the new ion-date and try to implement your old style using CSS/modal properties. You might try something like this:

```
<ion-button id="open-modal">Open Datetime Modal</ion-button>
<ion-modal   
[initialBreakpoint]="0.5" trigger="open-modal">
  <ng-template>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-datetime></ion-datetime>
    </ion-content>
  </ng-template>
</ion-modal>
```

Here you can find more examples of how to use the new date-picker: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime#usage

And here you can find more info about styling/ using the modal:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal#inline-modal

Comment: no bro i only need cylindrical datetime picker the one i showd you in the image i have no choise need to use ionic 6 only

Comment: can you please implement datetime on ion-picker and send me the git repo? ion picker looks like the one in ionic5 datetime

Comment: @saikiran do you know if the ionic5 picker scroll with the mouse on the desktop?

Comment: yeah so how can that help me

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-datetime presentation="date" [preferWheel]="true"></ion-datetime>
```

This works for me, shows a date spinner with month / day / year wheels